# How to change plotly color? And get Warning: Specifying width/height in layout() is now deprecated. Please specify in ggplotly() or plot_ly()

Tags: r, layout, shiny, plotly, pie-chart

I received this Warning: Specifying width/height in layout() is now deprecated.Please specify in ggplotly() or plot_ly()

What this mean?

And, I really do not know why I cannot change the default color for my plot.
I changed the color of "marker = list(colors=c("#fda902","#73bad9")" many times, my plot colors are still default color.

```html
 plot_ly(mydata4, labels = ~variable, values = ~ value,marker = list(colors=c("#fda902","#73bad9")))%>%
      add_pie(hole = 0.6) %>%
      layout(autosize = F, width = 400, height = 400,
             xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
             yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE))
```

Comment: The warning is pretty clear. Add `, width = 400, height = 400` as arguments to your `plot_ly()` function call instead of `layout()`

Comment: @ismirsehregal i have the same error message. The layout() function works fine unless you try to add width and height. Any suggestions of how to set the height and width ?

Comment: As mentioned above, use `plot_ly(..., width = 400, height = 400)` instead of `layout`.