# Dynamic height/width resizing in ggplotly using width/height=100%

Tags: r, ggplot2, dynamic, size, ggplotly

I would like to create a plot with `ggplotly()` in `R` by allowing dynamic height/width so that it will look something like this in the html:

`<div id="htmlwidget-7c8a8e27b8ce66400314" style="width:100%;height:100%;" class="plotly html-widget"></div>`

with: `width/height=100%`

However, this doesn't seem to be allowed in `ggplotly()`:
This

`ggplotly(p, size=“100%”, height=“100%”)` will throw an error.

It looks like this is possible when using RShiny `plotlyOutput` (e.g. https://community.plotly.com/t/plotly-shiny-reactive-height-of-plots/1503/4).

Is there a way to do that from ggplotly() ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45479034/13440409

Comment: consider making it fullscreen will be an alternative: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69042546/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-full-screen-popup-window-of-a-plotly-chart-in-r/69096923#69096923

Comment: Thank you! It seems like there isn't a direct option to create images with dynamic resizing when using `ggplotly()`. I need to embed the figure in a webpage so at this point hacking the final html directly also works. Thanks